# How to understand dynamical spin structure factor?

Tags: quantum-monte-carlo, neutron-scattering

A newish area of interactions between quantum Monte Carlo (QMC) and experiments is in spin spectra. Recent improvements in stochastic analytic continuation have made it much easier to compare/extract the dynamical spin structure factor, which corresponds to the results of inelastic neutron scattering experiments.

Example of QMC spin structure factor: [Phys. Rev. X **7**, 041072 (2017)](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.041072)
Example of neutron scattering measurements: [Phys. Rev. Lett. **124**, 197203 (2020)](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.041072)

My problem is that I don't have a good intuition for **interpreting** these spectra. They represent a complex quantity that includes density of states, dispersion relations, gaps, and finite-temperature effects with a layer of noise on top.

**How to identify important features from the experiments avoid getting confused by artifacts?**

Comment: It would be great to get an answer from a neutron scattering person if there are any such people on here.

Comment: As it's one of our oldest unanswered questions now, I tried to make it easier by reducing it from two questions to one. Also if this question is no longer needed for you, then you could flag it for a mod to close it, since it would shorten our unanswered list. If someone has an answer they can comment to ask for it to be re-opened.

Comment: I'm open to closing it for now.

Comment: To future readers: The user requested this question be temporarily closed. If you would like to provide an answer, comment here and the question can be reopened.